# What happens if you edit a php script while an instance of it is running?

Tags: php, apache

When you overwrite a php file on a server (say, via SFTP) while it is being processed somewhere (perhaps it's a script that takes several seconds to compelete) does it cancel the currently running script or does that finish out even after the overwrite occurs? I suppose I'm asking: does apache load a php script into memory before executing it (and does it hold on to that in memory for the duration of execution)?

Comment: depends on your platform. Windows tends to lock files that in use/executing. Unix-ish platforms are more lenient, and allow you to delete/replace files while they're in use, but only "new" processes will see the new files, and already-executing ones will continue to use the now invisible old file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> does apache load a php script into memory before executing it (and does it hold on to that in memory for the duration of execution)?

Yes.

Comment: It also depends if your server has APC cache enabled and it's TTL and garbage collection settings. Then if you're behind a load balancer that has additional caching there might be lag there. But for the most part, yes it is cached and shouldn't have any effect by editing it in place. Your text editor technically is putting the file into memory as well until it gets written to disk.

Comment: What if the script is running over the command line?  I'm guessing it is still loaded into memory for the duration of execution?

Answer (score 9):

Nothing at all. The script has already been loaded into memory in its compiled state - no matter how much time it takes, the web server won't load the new file unless you refresh the page.